In weblogic 14.1 what is the difference between "page-check-seconds" and "resource-reload-check-secs"
I can see what the definitions are based on the weblogic doumentation but not clear to me how they differ in practical application.  Also, currently using the "resource-reload-check-secs" in a production environment with 60 in order to catch and update the content change on a specific html file within the domain, in order to avoid a domain recycle.  This will obviously apply to all resources in the domain.  Am I creating a performance issue by running this in production environment.  is there any way to limit this parameter to be applicable to a specific resource only without disturbing the rest?  Thanks.
I have no issues currently with the way the functionality working.  I am just looking to see if there is a better way of doing this.
